# Change the quota size for an APFS volume

Tags: apfs

I created one APFS Container for the whole of my external hard drive.

I created several volumes in that - some with quotas.

I have now discovered that one quota is now too small. I used `diskutil apfs list /dev/disk10` to show me the Capacity consumed and the Capacity Quota.

How do I change the quota for an APFS volume under BigSur?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change an APFS reserveSize nor QuotaSize without destroying the APFS volume and recreating it.  You can only set these values when adding the APFS volume.

Comment: I suspect this is true but do you have any source for this?

Comment: It is true that there's no way to do this with `diskutil` which means for most people's purposes it's not possible. That said, I do not know is this is truly technically impossible, for some reason, or if it's just that changing these things is a can of worms Apple didn't want to deal with so this functionality is left absent. If you find a way to do it, I'd love to know.