# On Monterey, how to have "/System/Volumes/Data" use more space than its 90 GB quota?

Tags: apfs, disk-space

My "/System/Volumes/Data"'s container still have 34.3 GB free space

```
+-- Container disk3 D4363BE0-2F5E-4275-8726-57B5EA22FF63
|   ====================================================
|   APFS Container Reference:     disk3
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      317999996928 B (318.0 GB)
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   283670114304 B (283.7 GB) (89.2% used)
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       34329882624 B (34.3 GB) (10.8% free)
```

But the "/System/Volumes/Data" volume itself has a 90 GB quota, preventing me to install larger apps into `/Applications`

```
|   +-> Volume disk3s3 078F8B0F-A57E-4C49-95B2-3B3F978AFDBF
|   |   ---------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk3s3 (Data)
|   |   Name:                      Monterey - Data (Case-insensitive)
|   |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
|   |   Capacity Consumed:         82793533440 B (82.8 GB)
|   |   Capacity Reserve:          None
|   |   Capacity Quota:            90000003072 B (90.0 GB) (92.0% reached)
|   |   Sealed:                    No
|   |   FileVault:                 No
```

I'm aware that "there is no way to change an APFS reserveSize nor QuotaSize without destroying the APFS volume and recreating it" (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/421459/211312) 2 years ago.

Has things changed since then? I'm on Monterey 12.6.7 now.

diskutil is not helpful in suggesting me to resize the container, as the container already have enough free space for my needs.

```
% diskutil resizeVolume disk3s3 120G
disk3s3 is an APFS Volume (use "diskutil apfs list" to find its APFS Container and Physical Store(s) and then use "diskutil apfs resizeContainer" instead)
```